# Facebook Like-Button und Twitter-Button do not show side by side in mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a weird problem with my facebook Like-Button: On mobile browsers (Dolphin, Opera Mobile and Mini) the like button is pushing my twitter-button into the next line.

However, on desktop browsers (FF, Opera, IE), everything works just fine as desired, facebook button and twitter button lie side by side in one line. Can somebody help?

CSS for fb and twitter:

```
.fb-like {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    width:0px;
    height: 0px;
    color: #004993;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 10px;
    font-weight: bold; 
}

.twitter-share-button {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 140px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
```

PHP for fb and twitter:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false"></div>

<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="filmfutter" data-lang="de">Twittern</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

JavaScript SDK for fb-like-button:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/de_DE/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=403577219675479";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

</script>
```

Comment: Try wrapping both in a div with the `display:inline;` attribute.

Comment: How would I do that? Like `<div class=layout><div class="fb-like"...></div> <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button"...</div>` and then in CSS `.layout {display: inline; }` ?

Comment: Sorry, for each of them. You can add them into the classes that you already have. And I think without the `float:left`

Comment: You mean `.fb-like {display:inline;}` without `float:left` and `.twitter-share-button {display: inline;)` ? Or 2 divs for each class and then wrapping both in another div?

Comment: No, forget my first comment. I'll only wrap all of them if I need to group them and style them together.

Comment: Ok. Unfortunately `.fb-like {display:inline;}` without `float:left` and `.twitter-share-button {display:inline;}` doesn't seem to work as well.